# IBM Worklight: Change Text of BusyIndicator

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a busy indicator and defined the text of the busy indicator globally as below.

```
WL.ClientMessages.loading = "Please Wait...";
var busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator('content');
```

When busyInd.show() is invoked, the loading icon can be shown successfully with "Please Wait...".

Since my mobile app supports multiple language, I have some functions (e.g. setEnglish(), setFrench()) which specify the translated message for different keys. The key WL.ClientMessages.loading has been added to the functions but the message does not change.

Can the text be changed after the busy indicator object is created?

Thanks.

Environment: Worklight 5.0.6

Comment: In my experience no, ive had to create and destroy it when im changeing the text.  If there is another way that would be great

Answer (score 0):

In 5.0.6 this is the behavior of BusyIndicator by design - it is created with some text and uses it throughout its lifetime. 
So - a simple way to bypass the problem would be to create a new object after each setLaunguage().